# Putting a string on same line tcl

Tags: bash, tcl

I have a nmap output and I need to put strings on different lines on same line.

Nmap Output:

```
 Nmap scan report for 169.254.0.1
 Host is up (0.014s latency).
 Not shown: 97 closed ports
 PORT     STATE SERVICE
 80/tcp   open  http
 1720/tcp open  H.323/Q.931
 5060/tcp open  sip
 Device type: VoIP adapter|WAP|PBX|webcam|printer
```

New Ouput:

169.254.0.1,Voip adapter

How can I do this on tcl or bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Tcl`, we can use `regexp` to extract the required data.

```
set nmap_output "Nmap scan report for 169.254.0.1
 Host is up (0.014s latency).
 Not shown: 97 closed ports
 PORT     STATE SERVICE
 80/tcp   open  http
 1720/tcp open  H.323/Q.931
 5060/tcp open  sip
 Device type: VoIP adapter|WAP|PBX|webcam|printer"

if {[regexp {scan\s+report\s+for\s+(\S+).*Device\s+type:\s+([^|]+)} $nmap_output match ip type]} {
    puts $ip,$type
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Brute force:

```
<your_nmap_output> |  \
egrep "Nmap scan report|Device type" | \
sed -r 's/[ ]*Nmap scan report for (.*)$/\1,/' | \
sed -r 's/[ ]*Device type: ([^\|]*)\|.*/\1/' |  \
xargs
```